# JS. Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript

Initial code:

```
var bestproducts = {}

data.forEach(function(element,index) {
  bestproducts[element.shop_id][index] = element.product_data
}
```

During the first iteration I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

The only solution I have come across is the following:

```
var bestproducts = []

data.forEach(function(element,index) {
  if(!bestproducts[element.shop_id]){
    bestproducts[element.shop_id] = {}
    bestproducts[element.shop_id][index] = element.product_data
  } else {
    bestproducts[element.shop_id][index] = element.product_data
  }
}
```

**QUESTION**: if there a shorter/more elegant solution in this case?

Comment: put the identical line out of the `if` and remove the `else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. You need to define some object before assigning to it.

A more elegant way to do assigning would be something like:

```
var bestproducts = []

data.forEach(function(element,index) {
  bestproducts[element.shop_id] = bestproducts[element.shop_id] || {};
  bestproducts[element.shop_id][index] = element.product_data;
}
```

`bestproducts[element.shop_id] || {}` for the first time `bestproducts[element.shop_id]` is undefined therefore the first value you will assign empty object.
For the rest of the iteration `bestproducts[element.shop_id]` is not undefined, so it will assign `bestproducts[element.shop_id]` to itself.

Comment: You can by directly initializing the object that is assigned to `bestproducts[element.shop_id]`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make something like this, initializing `bestproducts[element.shop_id]` directly with an object with its own properties.

```js
var data = [{shop_id: "a1", product_data: "a1_prod"}, {shop_id: "a2", product_data: "a2_prod"}];
var result = "";

var bestproducts = {};

data.forEach(function(element,index) {
  bestproducts[element.shop_id] = { [index]: element.product_data };
  result += bestproducts[element.shop_id][index] + " ";
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Ofcourse, all the result stuff is just for visualization and can be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

With the object spread operator this could be considered a cleaner solution:

```
var bestproducts = []

data.forEach(function(element,index) {
  bestproducts[element.shop_id] = {
    ...bestproducts[element.shop_id],
    [index]: element.product_data,
  }
}
```

However I think a cleaner version of your original code is the best approach:

```
var bestproducts = []

data.forEach(function(element,index) {
  if(!bestproducts[element.shop_id]){
    bestproducts[element.shop_id] = {} 
  }
  bestproducts[element.shop_id][index] = element.product_data
}
```